# Mock azure cli commands with Pester

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, pester

I have a buch of Azure Cli scripts that I have put inside a powershell function, for example:

```
function NewAppRegistration($name, $replyUrls, $resourceAccessesFilePath) {   
    $appRegistration = az ad app create `
        --display-name $name `
        --reply-urls $replyUrls `
        --oauth2-allow-implicit-flow true `
        --available-to-other-tenants false `
        -o json | 
    ConvertFrom-Json

    if (Test-Path $resourceAccessesFilePath) {
        $appRegistration = az ad app update `
        --id $appRegistration.appId `
        --required-resource-accesses $resourceAccessesFilePath
    }

    return $appRegistration
}
```

And I want to mock `az ad app create` but I have no clue how to proceed and I also don't find any example of how to to that. Of course I could end up creating for every `az` command my own powershell function and I could mock these functions, but I wonder if it could not be made easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mock a bash command like `az` or any other kind is:

```
Mock az {}
```

For the assertion:

```
Should -Invoke -CommandName "az" -Exactly -Times 1 -ParameterFilter { 
            "$args" -match "ad app create" -and
            "$args" -match "--display-name $expectedName" -and
            "$args" -match "--reply-urls" -and (-not (Compare-Object $args[6] $expectedReplyUrls)) -and
            "$args" -match "--oauth2-allow-implicit-flow true" -and
            "$args" -match "--available-to-other-tenants false" -and
            "$args" -match "-o json"
        }
```

This is not documented by Pester and this solution was based [on this github issue](https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/1883#issuecomment-805165564)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the mocks for your az commands:

```
Mock az -MockWith { '{"data": "expected az json response"}' } -ParameterFilter { "$args" -match "ad app create" }
Mock az -MockWith { '{"data": "expected az json response"}' } -ParameterFilter { "$args" -match "ad app update" }
```

You can use the mock response to test all your script code

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to mock functions that aren't written in PowerShell unless you wrap those commands in a PowerShell function. However, there is a native Microsoft-written PowerShell module that might suit your needs. You could easily mock these functions without creating wrapper functions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-5.7.0

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Check my answer.